# Readiness probe (hdfs): minikube

Tags: kubernetes, hdfs, minikube, crashloopbackoff

i got a pod who's crashing : [image]

i tried `kubectl describe pod hdfs-datanode-2` and i get this :

[image]

[image]
NB: i've installed hdfs with helm chart

Comment: that's not helpful to debug, you can check the logs also if any available using the `kubectl logs <podname>`

Comment: @HarshManvar i added kubectl logs hdfs-datanode-2 screenshot

Comment: Please share output as text, not images